# How to wrap up long text in a Single cell using iReport Designer Tool 5.5.0?

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.5.0 and having a problem in wrapping a very long text in a Single Cell.

[image]

Also, I am trying to create a css in Styles but as it has also properties, so  I cannot manually write any code in the same.

I have tried Position type, Stretch type, Stretch with Over flow , print when detail Overflows, but it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="REPORTE_DE_INSPECCION" pageWidth="2830" pageHeight="555" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="2830" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="168d24ce-7867-4f8c-9bce-e72eb9f7b2b0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="0.75"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 2_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Comentario" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF" fill="Solid" pattern="">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="New Dataset 1" uuid="0d3f82f6-11a1-49ff-8329-0a1bf93ea51a">
        <field name="nro_inspeccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="num_Secu_pol" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="tipo_poliza" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="num_pol1" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="num_pol_cotiz" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="canal" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="num_end" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="cod_ramo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nom_producto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="sim_subproducto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="descSUbproducto" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fechaFormalizo" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="creacion" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="placa" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="agente" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="cod_agencia" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nom_agencia" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fecha" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="fechaInclusion" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="reqInspeccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="CanalExp" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="asegurable" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="comentario" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="centro_revision" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="blindado" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="localidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="desc_localidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="nombre_agente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Documents and Settings\\Seguros\\Mis documentos\\Downloads\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="REPORT_AUTOR" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <field name="nro_inspeccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="num_Secu_pol" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="tipo_poliza" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="num_pol1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="num_pol_cotiz" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="canal" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="num_end" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="cod_ramo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nom_producto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="sim_subproducto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="descSUbproducto" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fechaFormalizo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="creacion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="placa" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="agente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="cod_agencia" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nom_agencia" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fecha" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="fechaInclusion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="reqInspeccion" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CanalExp" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="asegurable" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="comentario" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="centro_revision" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="blindado" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="localidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="desc_localidad" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nombre_agente" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="10" y="0" width="2810" height="50" uuid="76e1f5d4-15e9-41fc-8ba0-c8628f3be9af"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="20" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Reporte de Inspección]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="60" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table" style="table" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="10" y="0" width="2810" height="60" uuid="b3af58be-cf70-491c-b671-a133e88cf4fa"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="New Dataset 1" uuid="bddaf903-8687-475b-9f09-8b0b23e0d67c">
                        <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="73d57505-00c4-47de-af47-6f89c222b41f">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="1cf8527e-398c-4a68-a55b-79a31592811c"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nombre Sub Producto]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="c79ee515-b8aa-4449-9b3e-e8de21fe1b38"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descSUbproducto}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="688bd5e0-69be-4ec5-9883-37d21f617b0e">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="f30e5f92-f0d1-4b3b-9318-9954de582c7f"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Formalización cotizacion o emision]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="4be7af2f-d974-498e-8c09-1ed35e8a1581"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                    <paragraph tabStopWidth="80"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaFormalizo}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="8b6d6e6b-80f2-47e2-abf9-dd45bd8a93d9"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Emision Registro]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{creacion}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="50" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="561a2566-8395-47a6-aa94-bba2adb02606"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Placa]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{placa}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="e0bc4174-51ba-4fd2-a28a-bf913ead3e0d">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="c47eb207-fe06-482a-9955-c3c45961bcc4"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Codigo Agente]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="84ee2f84-3083-40e5-9144-a3d93ef98623"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{agente}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="63173919-8fe3-48ba-be5f-0f064af226d3">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="eb00197c-7d83-4121-821d-2bf8b06c4d75"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nombre Agente ]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="b6bb26ce-a5b4-40e9-b6f7-0fba917657ef"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nombre_agente}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="313dc0ef-8485-4847-933e-11df4671c411">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="ce6f3fca-0265-4691-a779-64bce723df63"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Cod Agencia]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="fec185f2-2304-41a0-a068-8dc30f212f21"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{cod_agencia}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="fbe418a1-80bd-4696-a26c-11a06ab4cbe3">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="8e9bfa3c-6ae1-461e-a0b5-36064f00774b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nombre Agencia]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="6be04f48-e6c4-4708-9c8a-e723d89e95fc"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nom_agencia}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="fedb0d2b-4c6e-4ff2-ae0b-a703ed3e7353">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="bb23071c-c300-43db-9e5a-73366abe0bba"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Localidad ]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="ca22aafd-d1fb-41dd-b2fe-206bdb2cf2a1"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{localidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="110" uuid="c1f75fd8-cf3d-4177-b29c-29247710a6dd">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="110" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="96af8f9f-7bdf-4a12-ba81-793177557da6"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Nombre localidad]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="110" height="60" uuid="766e6eb6-70b5-42d6-8485-e88c9fb1a6da"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{desc_localidad}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="16a182b9-dfce-4bf4-859b-4d14041704c9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="ee73f296-baaf-4fdb-9d30-72e60667c0a6"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Atencion Inspeccion]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f92f92a4-5af8-45b2-8c09-611a4a1ac1fd"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fecha}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="4efd6e36-4190-4d01-87aa-582687de6397">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="c284f6eb-c2d3-47f5-838f-94a5dc51e39b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Creacion Inspeccion]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="cbfc3b3c-68e4-468e-b339-db2b92a2ea95"/>
                                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fechaInclusion}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Requiere Inspección]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{reqInspeccion}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Canal Expedicion]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CanalExp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="90" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Asegurable]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{asegurable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="250" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Comentario]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="0" width="250" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <font size="7"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comentario}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Centro Revisión]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{centro_revision}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="77eec847-44fd-44c5-aeaf-c77d8347cfa9">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 2_TH" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="40" forecolor="#FBF1F1" backcolor="#008E4C" uuid="779a3bfe-fc28-4e07-8dcb-ad2b058779fa"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Blindado]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 2_TD" height="60" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="60" uuid="f7552270-75f3-4179-9350-6012206c173d"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font size="8"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{blindado}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Please post complete jrxml with all columns, there is probably a column that is not correctly defined that create multiple rows in excel.

Comment: Cannot Post the complete code here. The Limit is 30000 and my code is 40000. Is there any other place where I can post my code

Comment: Also if the data of this column is short then it is place in one column. In case of long text then it takes the next column only. (Just 2 Columns only not more than that in case of very large data also)

Comment: Try to make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem at least the jr:table, I think you need to check the other columns, have exactly the same height on both cell and textField.

Comment: @Petter Friberg, i have removed some of the colomns and after compile the jrxml getting the same error. If there will be any code error, then the error will be in this code. However, as I need to deliver it to the client, therefore i have changed the height from 60 to 190 and changed alignment from middle and center to left and top. In most of the cases it got resolved, but when the report get very large data in then it cover the last data. Hope you will find the mistake in code. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I have not tested, but since you have textField that stretch (overflows), I would set all other text field to stretch also so try to set on all textFields; stretchType: "Relative to Tallest Object" in jrxml it's this attribute  `stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject"` Hence you need all textFields in row to have same height. Let me know if that works.